# Responsive design, vertically and horizontally align a div within a div

Tags: html, responsive-design, alignment

Very simple concept:

- div-1 has a width of 90% and a height of 1000px,
- div-2 has a width of 20% (of div-1) with no height.

Can I centre div-2 both horizontally and vertically within div-1 using CSS?

Comment: If the div2 is variable, I'm not sure you can do it - would need JS to figure out the height of it, to be able to apply an offset

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. Use `position:relative;` on the outer container, `position:absolute` on the inner, and a few more styles (listed below)

```
.outer {
    width:90%;
    height:1000px;
    position:relative;
}
.inner {
    height:2px; /* To make it visible */
    width:20%;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    top:50%;

    transform:translateY(-50%); /* Optional; positions it perfectly in center. 
                                Alternatives include using negative margins
                                or javascript to compensate.Needs some prefixes*/
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ZLA4u/)

I'm not sure why you'd want an element to have a height of 0...